# Find max covered pair of nodes in a graph

Tags: java, graph-theory, vertex, edges

Im trying to take two nodes of a graph which amount to the most connected edges from that graph and return the value in a String. HOW!?

Starter code:

Write a solution method that returns the MAXIMUM coverage of the given power line infrastructure as represented by lines(edges), and k number of electric power poles(nodes).

```
public class Solution1 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Solution sol = new Solution();

  // Your solution may be tested with random input like this. 
  // The actual test cases will vary. 
  int[][] lines = new int[][] {
        {1,2},{1,3},{0,1},{0,3}
  };
  System.out.println(sol.getMaxCoverage(lines, 4)); // 4
  }
 }


class Solution {
   public String getMaxCoverage(int[][] lines, int k) {

   }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

- Decide how you wish to store the poles and lines connecting them
- Loop through the poles
- Keep track of the two ploles that have the most lines
- return the two poles that have the most lines